# Run code on Python Flask AppEngine startup in GCP

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

I need to have a TCP client that listens to messages constantly (and publish pub sub events for each message)

Since there is no Kafka in GCP, I'm trying to do it using my flask service (which runs using AppEngine in GCP).

I'm planning on setting the `app.yaml` as:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

But I can't figure out how to trigger code on the flask app startup.

I've tried running code in the `main.py` and also tried to manipulate the `main` function in it - but it obviously doesn't work as AppEngine doesn't run it.

Do you have any idea how can I init the listener on the Flask' app startup?

(Or any other offer regarding how should I implement a tcp client that sends pubsub events, or inserting to Big Query?)

Comment: I don't this is possible in the Python 3.x AppEngine environment. So is this "tcp client" connecting to a tcp server to fetch tasks? If this is the case, you probably need to run this as a containerized python app instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went for implementing a Kafka connector myself and using Kafka.

Comment: So you can't comment yet so I understand what you are doing here but maybe just add an edit to your question instead of an answer